# CORS policy error with angular 11 and php api

Tags: angular, .htaccess, codeigniter-3, rest, angular11

Here is my angular --version log

```
Angular CLI: 11.1.2
Node: 10.19.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 11.1.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1101.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1101.2
@angular-devkit/core            11.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.1.2
@angular/cli                    11.1.2
@schematics/angular             11.1.2
@schematics/update              0.1101.2
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.1.3
```

I am using PHP (Codeigniter) as my server-side language running on apache2.

I want to call an API from angular with auth headers and X API key.
Here is my angular code.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
// import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient){

  }
  title = 'My First Application';


  apiCheck(){
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Authorization','Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNA==')
        .set("x-api-key","sdfasdfasdfsadfsadfsdaf")
        .set("token","sadfsadfasdf")
        .set("Content-Type","application/json")
        
      
    }
  let request = this.http.get('http://localhost/ci/index.php/api/V1/againTest', httpOptions);
   request.subscribe(
      data=>{
          console.log(data);
      }
   );
  }
}
```

This is working fine when I request this API from Postman. But got this error when I called this API from the angular end.

[image]

I have enabled the cors from the server end by adding this.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
```

I have tried with the documentation for proxy setting also https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

here is my proxy.conf.json

```
{
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  }
```

add register it on angular.json file.

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-dream-app:build",
            "proxyConfig": "./proxy.conf.json"
          },
```

I have not found any working answer from anywhere.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this. I created proxy.config.json file in the application directory.

newApp/proxy.config.json

[image]

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

localhost:8080 backend url api.

launch the application.

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json
```

sample post process.

[image]